# How to format data from SQL Server with line breaks when displaying them in an html page?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to grab a set of instructions from a table in SQL server.

I inserted the data into the table with tips that I found on other treads, but it still does not render correctly when displayed in an html page.

This is the return of the SQL select statement

> '1. Complete the form and email it to xxxxx@xxxxx.xom.' +  CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) +         '2. If the amount requested is more than $xxx.00, then email the form to the CEO.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '3. After approval, the form must be sent to Accounts Payable.'`

I tried replacing the CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) with 
 like this,

```
string formInstructions = routeInstructions.Replace("CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)", "<br />");
```

but that does not work either.

[image: This is the HTML as rendered]

Comment: Are you using c# to format the string or can you modify the sql statement?  I would also want to view source on the screen shot to see what the html code looks like exactly.

Comment: Your replace isn't correct. You are looking for the string literal when what you want to find is the character.

Comment: I was able to find a solution on another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415695/javascript-forcing-a-line-break-after-the-point-if-i-have-one-word

Answer (score 0):

Replace `< br />` with `\n`.

Comment: I gave it a try, but still no go.  Is there a different way I should insert it into sql?  I just need it to move to a new line after the period.  It doesnt really matter to me how it is formatted in sql.  I just need it to display correctly in the browser.  Should this be something that is handled on the client side?